# Embedding php in javascripts

Tags: php, javascript

I was trying to embed some PHP into a javscript function that gets called from an onChange in a drop down list. the javascript function is in a .js file, I can get the DDL to call the function, however i cannot get the function to work with the php... eventually i am going to use the value selected in the DDL to access a DB and populate other fields from there, right now i am trying to get it to work with the php:

```
    function controllerType(){

       alert('outside php');
       <?php
       $message = "inside php";
       echo "alert('$message');";
       ?>

     }
```

The function prints the first alert but not the alert called in the php.

Comment: When you examine the JavaScript, do you see the PHP "as is" ?

Answer (score 4):

Your webserver probably isn't looking for PHP code in `.js` files by default.  You'll have to tell it to either look for PHP in those files or change the file extension to `.php`.

If you you want to try the former and you're running an Apache web server, try adding the following line to your `.htaccess` file:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js`

Comment: is there a way to make an onChange call a PHP function in a php file?

Comment: @user744480 That's a complicated topic and should be posted in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
function controllerType() {
    alert('outside php');
    alert('<?php echo $message; ?>');
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference from JavaScript's point of view.

Comment: I wouldn't think so either :-\

Comment: Now you're create PHP code with javascript, I think OP's idea was to create JS code with PHP :)

Comment: What are you talking about? You *can't* create PHP code with javascript, at least definietly not this way -- one would need an asycn/syncrhonous request to do that.... This is simply putting a PHP variable into his javascript code... So yes, I am creating JS code with PHP.. i dont know where you see it otherwise..

Answer (score 0):

You can't *call* an `alert()` in PHP.

PHP can just echo text the JavaScript interpreter can interpret as JavaScript.

As for the code you posted, that should all be ran by JavaScript fine. [CodePad](http://codepad.org/qaoFYyng).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $message = "inside php";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function controllerType(){
       alert('outside php');
       alert(<?=$message;?>);
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that your javascript is not being evaluated by your PHP parser.
You might have to create a separate document for that function which ends in .php or using a .htaccess (assuming you're using apache) to tell your php handler to parse .js files

Answer (score 0):

From your following sentence:

> eventually i am going to use the value
>   selected in the DDL to access a DB and
>   populate other fields from there

It really sounds like you are trying to have the PHP code execute at runtime within the browser. PHP is a server side language and you cannot simply use it in a javascript file as you are trying to.

You will need to have the javascript function post the value from the drop down list to a PHP page through a HTML form or through AJAX.

Forgive me if I misunderstood you.

Comment: It sounds like you understood what i was trying to get at, i basically need the page to reload displaying information retrieved from the database based on the value selected... so you are suggesting i create a javascript that sends the selected value to a new php page?

Comment: That is correct. You could do it simply by using window.location.href = "page.php?item=" + ddl_value; That would redirect the user to php page. The other way to do it without reloading the page is to use AJAX, have a look at the JQuery javascript library, it makes dealing with AJAX a lot easier.